# Asyncstorage remove item, it is not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, async-await, asyncstorage

```
const handleDeleteProduct = product => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Delete Product',
      `Are you sure you want to delete ${product.id}?`,
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          style: 'destructive',
          onPress: async (key = product.item) => {
            try {
              await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
              // RNRestart.Restart();
            } catch (e) {
              console.error(e);
            }
          },
        },
      ],
    );
  };
```

Please help me, this `removeItem` does not work, eventhough I follow the [documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api/)

I try to delete an Item using `onLong` event in `TouchableWithoutFeedback` element in a reactnative element, I enclose the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` in `flatlist`.

Comment: I guess the problem is more related to the `key` variable, have you tried rewriting it to `await AsyncStorage.removeItem(product.item)`, or print out the value of `key`?

Comment: How did you test the result?

Comment: yes I did the product.Item first, and it is still not working

Comment: After some thoughts, I guess the problem is most likely not related to the library,  and it might be caused by a simpler issue, for example the key is not `product.item`

Answer (score 0):

**work for me**

```
  import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'; <--import 

    async function removeItem(yourKey) {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem(yourKey);
        console.log(`Successfully removed item with key: ${yourKey}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error removing item with key: ${yourKey}`, error);
      }
    }


-> removeItem('yourKey');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
removeValue = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@MyApp_key')<---- you can use like this in '' brekets
  } catch(e) {
    // remove error
  }

  console.log('Done.')
}
```